# DOMContentLoaded not getting fired in typescript

Tags: typescript, progressive-web-apps, lit-element

I Am trying to fire DOMContentLoaded event in typescript after page load is completed.

I am unable to figure out where to put `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event ()=>{})` line, so that I can query for elements loaded as of now I am putting this code in consstructor of my web component class but its not firing.

Below is the code.

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
        this.domCompleteHandler(e)
    }, false);
}
 domCompleteHandler(e: Event) {
    //if (e.target!.readystatechange === "complete") {
        var chkbxes = document!.querySelector('my-app[apptitle="my app"]')!.shadowRoot!.querySelector('[active]')!.shadowRoot!.querySelector("#permSection")!.querySelector("#permtable")!.shadowRoot!.querySelector("#permtable")!.querySelectorAll(".permchk");
        chkbxes!.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                this.clickHandler(e);
            });
        });
    console.log(e);
    console.log(chkbxes);
    //}
}
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet the event has already fired. You should also be checking `document.readyState`

Comment: i checked by debugging. the code the debugger never went inside the addeventlistner method. I actually want to where should i put addEventListener method.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely situation here is that this event has already fired before this code has run.

You can test this by putting an event listener somewhere earlier in your application. One example would be to simply add the below script directly near the top of your HTML page:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('DOMContentLoaded fired');
  });
</script>
```

That should show the log message in your logs at the point when the event fires, which is likely before the object shown in your code sample above has been instantiated.

In general, this event fires when the main document has loaded and been parsed, but not subresources. This means that if your line of code is run asynchronously from the document loading (e.g. if it waits for a `fetch` or `setTimeout`, or if the `<script>` tag is marked as `async`) then it's very possible that the event will fire first.

There's one other option: the event might not be firing at all, because the DOM content really hasn't loaded yet. This is far more unlikely, but you can confirm the document state by checking the `document.readyState` global. If that's set to `interactive` or `complete` then the event has fired already.

Comment: its not javascript, its typescript. so i can not write this inside script tag.

Comment: The TypeScript part shouldn't matter for now. You can test with javascript. TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript, at runtime they're the same thing. You can test with JavaScript in an HTML script tag even in a TypeScript codebase.